# How do I use a proxy with Node and ESM?

Tags: node.js

In the olden days I had something like this...

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require("https-proxy-agent");
new HttpsProxyAgent(URL)
```

However when I convert to ESM...

```
import HttpsProxyAgent from "https-proxy-agent";
// Also tried
// import * as HttpsProxyAgent from "https-proxy-agent";
new HttpsProxyAgent(URL)
```

I get...

> (node:7856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: HttpsProxyAgent is not
>   a constructor

So how do I accomplish this now? Is there a native ES6 proxy that node supports?

Comment: Exporting any sort of function as `module.exports` in CommonJS became somewhat of a bad habit when ES6 module syntax was introduced to the specification. It's not guaranteed by the specification that `import * as ...` will actually retain the function and not just its properties. But to indirectly answer your question, `console.log(HttpsProxyAgent);` after `import HttpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent';` and that output should tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way works:

```
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do:

```
new HttpsProxyAgent.HttpsProxyAgent(URL);
```